# ASP.NET C# DetailsView edit with dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

Updated... since I am not able to resolve the problem and I probably posted a full codes (too much) and no one would read it...

Comment: I think that is `<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridViewID " Name="VendorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />` or something like that, but I am not sure if this is the solution to your question.

Comment: I am new, can you provide more details please?

Comment: You have not give here the full working code, you have miss the dropdown list, and some other details to be able to make a working example. How ever I think thing that you can make it by your self using just the mouse and select the correct options on the datasource on design view.

Comment: Full working code has been updated, please see if you can help. thanks

Comment: Sorry go for sleep now, I will continue tomorrow, if no other replay, but this is it, with the `ControlParameter`

Comment: I am totally stuck. anyone has any suggestions?